# Loop for add a json for each object in list

Tags: c#, json

I'm making a tool that needs to export a json. He needs to be in this format:

```
    {
      "version" : "2",
      "mangas" : [ {
        "manga" : [ "sample", "manganame", 1234567890, 0, 0 ],
        "chapters" : [ {
          "u" : "urlexample",
          "r" : 1
        }, {
          "u" : "urlexample",
          "r" : 1
        }, {
          "u" : "urlexample",
          "r" : 1
        } ]
      } ]
    }
```

And this is my code:

```
    void createJson(String manganame, String mangaoid, String sourceid)
            {
                String[] mangainfo = { "/manga/" + mangaoid, manganame, sourceid, "0", "0" };



                var root = new RootObject()
                {
                    version = "2",
                    mangas = new List<Manga>()
                    {
                        new Manga()
                        {

                            manga = mangainfo,
                            chapters = new List<Chapter>()
                            {
                                new Chapter
                                {

                                    u = "sample",
                                    r = 1

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                };


                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
                File.WriteAllText(@"D:\path.txt", json);
                Console.WriteLine(json);


            }
```

I'm lost, if someone can help me. Already give a search on Google, but the answer didn't come up in my head, already trying for a few time, slowly I'm getting but now is time to ask for help lol

For the list I was talking about, I'll explain it. I have a sqlite DB that have various information from mangas etc... I execute a query where I filter by a id, "SELECT * FROM MangaChapter WHERE manga_id = 'someid'", then i put the result on a list using a for loop. In the DB chapter url is stored like that "mr-chapter-166165" this is why i have had to concat string in chapterList.add.

```
   List<String> chapterList = new List<String>();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MangaChapter WHERE manga_id = '3252'";
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        chapterList.Add("/pagesv2?oid=" + reader.GetString("oid"));
    }
```

For reference this is what I'm using to manage the sqlite db https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.SQLite/

In the list, each chapter is something like that "/pagesv2?oid=mr-chapter-166165", if I print all the list on the console we'll be having something like that:

```
    /pagesv2?oid=mr-chapter-166165
    /pagesv2?oid=mr-chapter-166166
    /pagesv2?oid=mr-chapter-166167
```

Comment: My bad, already corrected it.

Comment: mangainfo needs to be an object[] containing 2 strings and 3 int

Comment: Okay. Aside from that, my code actually generate some json. I'm gonna five more context, the json generated needs to contain the manga name, source id etc... this is working well. Now my problem is that the json needs to contain the chapters released, regard in this part "new Chapter { u = "", r=1 }" each of this add one chapter to JSON. Here lies the problem, the chapters list is a List, and each manga have various chapters. So I was thinking if I have some way to "foreach chapter" the code gives a "new Chapter...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the classes I generated from the given JSON sample

```
public class Chapter
{
    [JsonProperty("u")]
    public string U { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("r")]
    public int R { get; set; }
}

public class Manga
{
    [JsonProperty("manga")]
    public IList<object> MangaInfos { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("chapters")]
    public IList<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mangas")]
    public IList<Manga> Mangas { get; set; }
}
```

and here the code to reproduce the give JSON sample

```
var d = new Example
{
    Version = "2",
    Mangas = new List<Manga>
    {
        new Manga()
        {
            MangaInfos = new List<object>{ "sample", "manganame", 1234567890, 0, 0 },
            Chapters = new List<Chapter>
            {
                new Chapter()
                {
                    U = "urlexample",
                    R = 1,
                },
                new Chapter()
                {
                    U = "urlexample",
                    R = 1,
                },
                new Chapter()
                {
                    U = "urlexample",
                    R = 1,
                },
            },
        },
    },
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d,Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The output looks like

```
{
  "version": "2",
  "mangas": [
    {
      "manga": [
        "sample",
        "manganame",
        1234567890,
        0,
        0
      ],
      "chapters": [
        {
          "u": "urlexample",
          "r": 1
        },
        {
          "u": "urlexample",
          "r": 1
        },
        {
          "u": "urlexample",
          "r": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and live view at [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LfM6CH)

Comment: Yeah. That's pretty much the output that's needed. Now a problem, exactly that part "new Chapter() {  U = "urlexample", R = 1, }" where you need to repeat that for add another chapter. We have some way to get that in a loop (foreach, for..)?. Example, a certain manga have 700 chapters, it's not something that you want to write, supposing we have 3 "Mangas" and each 300 chapters. Let's think about, if I have a List with the url of all the chapters, how can i make  "new Chapter() {  U = "urlexample", R = 1, }" for each chapter without manually typing. Thank's for the replies.

Comment: I do not know how your list looks like. How can I show you how to build this with your list I do not know?

Comment: Very sorry for that. My mistake. I already edited the post, if you wanna something else just say it.

Comment: Well, that is a list of strings, but how do we get the informations we need to fill the chapter list?

Comment: Yes. I retrieve the information from a sqlite db, I just edited posting the code about that.

Comment: Hmmm, I tend to have some application objects to store the informations and for export I map that informations to the export classes and serialize them. Look at the sample [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rMoTTZ)

Comment: Yet this don't solve my problem of having to type manually each chapter. But I got an idea. I'm gonna test right now.

Comment: You should have some source (f.i. database) where you can iterate over the chapters and so build a collection from that. If not, yes then you have to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if you want to have various chapters for each "Manga", you have to change your data structure and that changes the Result Json you want.
maybe something like this?

```
public partial class Root
{
    public long Version { get; set; }
    public Mangas[] Mangas { get; set; }
}

public partial class Mangas
{
    public Manga[] Manga { get; set; }

}

public partial class Chapter
{
    public string U { get; set; }
    public long R { get; set; }
}

public partial struct Manga
{
    public long? Integer;
    public string String;
    public Chapter[] Chapters { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through chapters. Solution below.

```
    class Parent
    {
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public List<Manga> mangas { get; set; }
    }

    class Manga
    {

        public List<object> manga { get; set; }
        public List<Chapter> chapters { get; set; }

    }

    class Chapter
    {

        public  string u { get; set; }
        public int r { get; set; }

    }

    void createJson(String manganame, string mId, String mangaoid, long sourceid)
    {

        var json = new Parent()
        {
            Version = 2,
            mangas = new List<Manga>()
            {
                new Manga()
                {
                    manga = new List<object>{ "/manga/"+mangaoid, manganame, sourceid, 0, 0 },
                    chapters = Chapters(),
                }
            }
        };

        var sjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Izurii\Desktop\oi.json", sjson);

    }

    List<Chapter> Chapters()
    {
        List<Chapter> chapters = new List<Chapter>();
        for(int i = 0; i < links.Count; i ++)
        {
            chapters.Add(
            new Chapter()
            {
                u = links[i],
                r = 1,
            });

        }
        return chapters;
    }
```